# MySQL function alternative for me access datediff

Tags: mysql

Datediff('d', date1, date2) gives an error in MySQL.

But MySQL has a datediff function, and yet it is giving error

Comment: So what did the documentation say about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datediff in mysql has a different definition.

Try datediff(date2, date1), Also need to reverse the order of dates.

Next time, do read the docs before posting. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)